# How to send deleted files from android file system to recycle bin?

Tags: android

I have a problem to send deleted files into recycle bin in android and get restore back when I want. Can anybody help me for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Android doesn't have a recycle bin. just a simple deletion.

Even undelete operation is something that I can only find for rooted devices, and frankly (and sadly) none of them (that I've tried) work well.

The only thing that is similar to the recycle bin is apps that use root for this, but I have no idea how well they work and how they work at all. You could also customize your own ROM to have a recycle bin, and I think some ROMs already have it.